Why is the styling not applied correctly when printing the invoice using the QZ Tray library?
I am using QZ Tray in my React project to print invoices. The invoice structure looks fine on the screen, but when I print it, extra spaces appear. How can I fix this issue?
Here is my Invoice  Structure, Which i provide as ref to Qz-Tray
{/* Invoice Header */}
        
          <h6>Invoice # {invoice.id}</h6>
          <h6
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
              textAlign: "center",
              fontSize: "0.75rem",
              color: "#1f2937",
            }}
          >
            Punched By: {invoice.user?.fullName || ""}
          </h6>
        
        <h6
          style={{
            fontSize: "0.75rem",
            color: "#1f2937",
          }}
        >
          Date: {dayjs(invoice.createdAt).format("D MMM, YYYY, h:mm A")}
        </h6>

        {/* Order Information */}
        <h5
          style={{
            marginTop: "0.5rem",
            textAlign: "center",
            fontSize: "1.125rem",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            color: "#1f2937",
          }}
        >
          Order # {invoice.orderNo.split("-")[1]}
        </h5>

        {/* Table Information */}
        {invoice.tableId && (
          <h6 style={{ textAlign: "center", fontSize: "0.875rem", fontWeight: "bold", color: "#1f2937" }}>
            {`${invoice.table?.tableNo} ${invoice.table?.floor?.level}`}
          </h6>
        )}

        {/* Order Type & Customer Details */}
        <div style={{ marginTop: "0.25rem" }}>
          {invoice.employee && invoice.employee.name && (
            <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
              <span style={{ fontSize: "0.75rem", fontWeight: "bold", color: "#1f2937" }}>Waiter:</span>
              <span style={{ fontSize: "0.75rem", fontWeight: "bold", color: "#1f2937" }}>
                {invoice.employee.name}
              </span>
            </div>
          )}
          <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
            <span style={{ fontSize: "0.75rem", fontWeight: "bold", color: "#1f2937" }}>Order Type:</span>
            <span style={{ fontSize: "0.75rem", fontWeight: "bold", color: "#1f2937" }}>{invoice.invoiceType}</span>
          </div>

          {invoice.invoiceType !== "DineIn" && invoice.customerId && (
            <>
              <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
                <span style={{ fontSize: "0.75rem", fontWeight: "bold", color: "#1f2937" }}>Customer Name:</span>
                <span style={{ fontSize: "0.75rem", color: "#1f2937" }}>{invoice.customer?.name}</span>
              </div>
              <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
                <span style={{ fontSize: "0.75rem", fontWeight: "bold", color: "#1f2937" }}>Phone No:</span>
                <span style={{ fontSize: "0.75rem", color: "#1f2937" }}>{invoice.customer?.contact}</span>
              </div>
              <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
                <span style={{ fontSize: "0.75rem", fontWeight: "bold", color: "#1f2937" }}>Address:</span>
                <span style={{ fontSize: "0.75rem", color: "#1f2937" }}>{invoice.customer?.address}</span>
              </div>
            </>
          )}
        </div>

        {/* Products List */}
        <div style={{ marginTop: "0.5rem" }}>
          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "space-between",
              fontSize: "0.875rem",
              fontWeight: "bold",
              color: "#1f2937",
            }}
          >
            <span style={{ width: "50%" }}>Product</span>
            <span style={{ width: "16.6667%", textAlign: "center" }}>Qty</span>
          </div>

          {getAppropriateItems().map((item, id) => (
            <div
              key={id}
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "space-between",
                borderBottom: "1px solid",
                padding: "0.25rem 0",
                fontSize: "11px",
                color: "#1f2937",
              }}
            >
              <span style={{ width: "50%" }}>
                {item.product.name}
                {item.description && (
                  <>
                    <br />
                    {item.description}
                  </>
                )}
              </span>
              <span style={{ width: "16.6667%", textAlign: "center" }}>{getAppropriateQuantity(item)}</span>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>

        {/* Note and Footer */}
        <p style={{ paddingTop: "0.25rem", fontSize: "0.75rem", color: "#1f2937" }}>
          <b>Note:</b> {invoice.kotNote}
        </p>
        <p
          style={{
            marginTop: "0.5rem",
            textAlign: "center",
            fontSize: "0.75rem",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            color: "#1f2937",
          }}
        >
          Powered by: XYZ
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

Here is the Function
const handlePrint = async ref => {
    try {
      
      // Ensure no duplicate connections
      if (!qz.websocket.isActive()) {
        await qz.websocket.connect();
      }

      // List available printers
      const printers = await qz.printers.find();
      console.log("Available Printers:", printers);

      // Create a printer config (adjust printer name accordingly)
      const config = qz.configs.create("POS-80");
      await qz.print(config, [
        {
          type: "pixel",
          format: "html",
          flavor: "plain",
          data: ref.innerHTML,
        },
      ]);

      console.log("Print completed");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    } finally {
      // Ensure proper disconnection
      if (qz.websocket.isActive()) {
        await qz.websocket.disconnect();
      }
    }
};


Hi, QZ Tray uses the JavaFX HTML rendering engine, so things won't render identically to Chrome or Firefox, so it's likely due to a compatibility difference between your CSS in QZ Tray versus the browser you would normally use for testing.  Would you be able to edit the HTML snippet into a raw HTML example that still reproduces the issue (without the {{ ... }} syntax)?

Thank you very much! I fixed the problem. Qz-Tray does not support any styling frameworks like Tailwind CSS or Bootstrap. Additionally, it does not work properly if I apply styles from a separate CSS file and include it in my React component. Styling only works with inline styles, and it is functioning correctly now.

Hi, for clarification, JavaFX is based on Webkit and does support most features of Tailwind, Bootstrap as well as external CSS files,  but due to how QZ Tray works, inlining is often better.
